# How do I change dracut-initqueue timeout?

Tags: centos, initramfs, timeout, dracut

During boot, my CentOS 7 box yields a bunch of messages like `[  202.161851] myhost dracut-initqueue[381]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts` and then drops me to a prompt.  I wait a few minutes for my storage to finish loading and then type `exit` and the boot completes.

How do I change the timeout so instead of giving me a prompt after a couple minutes it actually waits for the storage to load and boots automatically?  I initiate most reboots remotely and it is really annoying to have to jump on the console every time I reboot just to type `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

when you see install CentOS screen, move the arrow up to "install CentOS 7"
then press `tab`,
It will show the parameter it is passing.
remove the line until `hd:` and add "sr0"
then press enter.

I think that will do it.

if didn't work, try to find the device name of the cdrom or USB mounted to install,
Try `ll /dev/disk/by-id/` you will get an idea which drive is device to append to `hd:` as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot in rescue.  If you can, then you should regenerate initramfs.  For example,

```
dracut -f /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64.img 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
```

The OS will be able to boot up normally afterwards.

Thanks TrevorH for this solution: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63988

> Re: Change VM - 'Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout' at startup Post
> by TrevorH » 2017/09/08 16:08:32
>
> All of the things you tried will not work. You need something like
> dracut -f /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-514.26.2.e17.x86_64.img
> 3.10.0-514.26.2.e17.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You can change this via `rd.timeout` option. There are several other timeouts which has been recently added, see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html